# Instances registered as singleton in DI container created multiple times in Xamarin forms app

Tags: android, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, dependency-injection

I've created an app for Android using Xamarin forms but have a problem. We log the android life cycle events and I saw an onDestory immediately followed by an OnCreate android lifecycle event.

- 2024-01-26 09:18:41.565 +01:00 [Information]: OnDestroy executed.
- 2024-01-26 09:18:42.294 +01:00 [Information]: OnCreate executed.

After this happened, the DI container is created a second time. We know this because some services in the container are registered as singleton background services that log their own output and thread id in every log.

How can I fix this? Here is the relevant code where I start the app:

Mainactivity:

```
namespace Peripass.YardAssetManagementApp.Droid {
  [Activity(Label = "Peripass Operations",
    Icon = "@mipmap/ic_launcher",
    Theme = "@style/MainTheme",
    MainLauncher = false, ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait, LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop)]
  public class MainActivity : FormsAppCompatActivity {

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      Serilog.Log.Information($"{nameof(OnCreate)} executed.");
      AndroidContext.Context = this;

      CachedImageRenderer.Init(true);
      ForLinker.Link(); //Need to force linker to reference this library.

      TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
      ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

      base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

      Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
      Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

      if (IsPlayServiceAvailable() == false) {
        throw new Exception("This device does not have Google Play Services and cannot receive push notifications.");
      }
      LoadApplication(new App());
      StartPushNoticationChannel();
    }

    //other code in the class

  }
}
```

App class:

```
namespace Peripass.YardAssetManagementApp {
  public partial class App : Application, IApp {
    
    public App() {
      ConfigureSerilog();
      DependencyResolver.ResolveUsing(type => ServiceProvider.GetService(type));
      ConfigureServices();
      InitializeComponent();
      AppCenter.Start($"android={Configuration.Configuration.ApplicationInsightsKeyAndroid};", typeof(Analytics), typeof(Crashes));
      MainPage = ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MainPage>();
    }

    public IServiceCollection Services { get; } = new ServiceCollection();
    public IServiceProvider ServiceProvider { get; set; }

    private void ConfigureSerilog() {
      Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .WriteTo.File($"{Constants.LogFilesDirectory}logs.txt", 
          rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day, 
          fileSizeLimitBytes: 2000000, 
          rollOnFileSizeLimit: true,
          retainedFileCountLimit: 6,
          outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level}]: {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}")
        .CreateLogger();
    }

    private void ConfigureServices() {
      RegisterPlatformSpecificServices();

      Services.AddSingleton<ILifecycleHooksService, LifecycleHooksService>();
      Services.AddTransient<INetworkInformationProvider, NetworkInformationProvider>();
      Services.AddTransient<IPolicyFactory, PolicyFactory>();

      RegisterLocalDataServices();
      RegisterRemoteDataServices();
      RegisterSyncLogic();
      RegisterServices();

      RegisterViews();
      Services.AddSingleton<IUserManager, UserManager>();
      Services.AddSingleton<ILogger, Logger>();
      Services.AddSingleton<INavigationService, NavigationService>();
      Services.AddSingleton<StepsWizardManager>();
      Services.AddSingleton<MainPage>();
      Services.AddSingleton<IRestServiceHelper, RestServiceHelper>();
      Services.AddSingleton<IPushNotificationsService, PushNotificationsService>();
      Services.AddSingleton<IBackgroundDataCleaningService, BackgroundDataCleaningService>();
      Services.AddSingleton<IMediaService, MediaService>();
      ServiceProvider = Services.BuildServiceProvider();
    }

    public void RegisterPlatformSpecificServices() {
      Services.AddSingleton(DependencyService.Get<ILocalFileSystem>());
      Services.AddSingleton(DependencyService.Get<INotificationRegistrationService>());
      Services.AddSingleton(DependencyService.Get<IHttpClientProvider>());
      Services.AddSingleton(DependencyService.Get<IPushNotificationTokenProvider>());
      Services.AddSingleton(DependencyService.Get<IVersionProvider>());
      Services.AddSingleton(DependencyService.Get<IAppDestroyer>());
      var notificationManager = DependencyService.Get<INotificationManager>();
      notificationManager.Initialize();
      Services.AddSingleton(notificationManager);
    }

    public void RegisterServices() {
      Services.AddTransient<ITaskService, TaskService>();
      Services.AddTransient<ILocationService, LocationService>();
      Services.AddTransient<ILocalizationService, LocalizationService>();
      Services.AddTransient<IDiagnosticsService, DiagnosticsService>();
      Services.AddTransient<IUserLifeCycleEventsService, UserLifeCycleEventsService>();
    }

    public void RegisterLocalDataServices() {
      Services.AddSingleton<ILocalTaskDataService, LocalTaskDataService>();
      Services.AddSingleton<ILocalLocationDataService, LocalLocationDataService>();
      Services.AddSingleton<ILocalUserDataService, LocalUserDataService>();
      Services.AddSingleton<ILocalPushNotificationDataService, LocalPushNotificationDataService>();
      Services.AddSingleton<ILocalPictureDataService, LocalPictureDataService>();
      Services.AddSingleton<ISafeFileSystem, SafeFileSystem>();
      Services.AddSingleton<ILocalLocalizationDataService, LocalLocalizationDataService>();
      Services.AddSingleton<ILocalDiagnosticsDataService, LocalDiagnosticsDataService>();
    }

    public void RegisterRemoteDataServices() {
      Services.AddSingleton<IRemoteTaskDataService, RemoteTaskDataService>();
      Services.AddSingleton<IRemoteLocationDataService, RemoteLocationDataService>();
      Services.AddSingleton<IRemoteUserDataService, RemoteUserDataService>();
      Services.AddSingleton<IRemoteFileDataService, RemoteFileDataService>();
      Services.AddSingleton<IRemoteLocalizationDataService, RemoteLocalizationDataService>();
      Services.AddSingleton<IAuthenticationDataService, AuthenticationDataService>();
      Services.AddSingleton<IRemoteDeviceDataService, RemoteDeviceDataService>();
      Services.AddSingleton<IRemoteTaskTemplateDataService, RemoteTaskTemplateDataService>();
      Services.AddSingleton<IRemoteDiagnosticsDataService, RemoteDiagnosticsDataService>();
    }

    public void RegisterSyncLogic() {
      Services.AddSingleton<IToMobileTasksSyncer, ToMobileTasksSyncer>();

      Services.AddSingleton<IQueue, IncommingHighPriorityQueue>();
      Services.AddSingleton<IQueue, IncommingLowPriorityQueue>();
      Services.AddSingleton<IQueue, OutgoingHighPriorityQueue>();
      Services.AddSingleton<IQueue, OutgoingLowPriorityQueue>();
      Services.AddSingleton<IQueue, PictureSyncLowPriorityQueue>();
      Services.AddSingleton<IQueue, PictureSyncHighPriorityQueue>();

      Services.AddSingleton<IQueueOrchestrator, IncommingQueueOrchestrator>();
      Services.AddSingleton<IQueueOrchestrator, OutgoingQueueOrchestrator>();
      Services.AddSingleton<IQueueOrchestrator, PictureQueueOrchestrator>();

      Services.AddSingleton<IQueueProcessor, IncommingQueueProcessor>();
      Services.AddSingleton<IQueueProcessor, OutgoingQueueProcessor>();
      Services.AddSingleton<IQueueProcessor, PictureQueueProcessor>();

      Services.AddSingleton<IQueueItemSyncAction, FetchTaskDetailSyncAction>();
      Services.AddSingleton<IQueueItemSyncAction, OutgoingStepValueUpdateSyncAction>();
      Services.AddSingleton<IQueueItemSyncAction, OutgoingTaskStatusChangedSyncAction>();
      Services.AddSingleton<IQueueItemSyncAction, SyncPictureAction>();

      Services.AddSingleton<IFileIntegrityHelper, FileIntegrityHelper>();
      Services.AddSingleton<IPictureSyncService, PictureSyncService>();
    }

    public void RegisterViews() {
      Services.AddTransient<LoginViewContent>();
      Services.AddSingleton<LoginViewModel>();

      Services.AddTransient<UserInfoViewContent>();
      Services.AddSingleton<UserInfoViewModel>();

      Services.AddTransient<MainTaskListViewContent>();
      Services.AddSingleton<MainTaskListViewModel>();

      Services.AddTransient<TaskDetailViewContent>();
      Services.AddSingleton<TaskDetailViewModel>();

      Services.AddTransient<IntegerFieldTaskStepViewContent>();
      Services.AddSingleton<IntegerFieldTaskStepViewModel>();

      Services.AddTransient<TextAreaTaskStepViewContent>();
      Services.AddSingleton<TextAreaTaskStepViewModel>();

      Services.AddTransient<DropDownTaskStepViewContent>();
      Services.AddSingleton<DropDownTaskStepViewModel>();

      Services.AddTransient<MoveToLocationSummaryViewContent>();
      Services.AddSingleton<MoveToLocationSummaryViewModel>();

      Services.AddTransient<TakePictureStepViewContent>();
      Services.AddSingleton<TakePictureStepViewModel>();

      Services.AddTransient<MoveToLocationStepViewContent>();
      Services.AddSingleton<MoveToLocationStepViewModel>();

      Services.AddTransient<TaskCompletedViewContent>();
      Services.AddSingleton<TaskCompletedViewModel>();

      Services.AddTransient<LoggedOutViewContent>();
      Services.AddSingleton<LoggedOutViewModel>();

      Services.AddTransient<TextFieldTaskStepViewContent>();
      Services.AddSingleton<TextFieldTaskStepViewModel>();

      Services.AddTransient<DecimalFieldTaskStepViewContent>();
      Services.AddSingleton<DecimalFieldTaskStepViewModel>();

      Services.AddTransient<GenericExceptionPageViewContent>();
      Services.AddSingleton<GenericExceptionPageViewModel>();

      Services.AddTransient<CleanupBeforeLogoutPageViewContent>();
      Services.AddSingleton<CleanupBeforeLogoutPageViewModel>();

      Services.AddTransient<SelectLanguageViewContent>();
      Services.AddSingleton<SelectLanguageViewModel>();

      Services.AddTransient<SelectTemplateViewContent>();
      Services.AddSingleton<SelectTemplateViewModel>();
      
      Services.AddTransient<AssetAndVisitorSelectionPageViewContent>();
      Services.AddSingleton<AssetAndVisitorSelectionPageViewModel>();

      Services.AddTransient<PreparingTaskPageViewContent>();
      Services.AddSingleton<PreparingTaskPageViewModel>();

    }

    protected override async void OnStart() {
      await ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILifecycleHooksService>().OnStart();
    }


    protected override async void OnResume() {
      await ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILifecycleHooksService>().OnResume();
    }
  }
}
```

**What am I doing wrong here? Why is my DI container created a second time? Why do I have duplicate singletons all of a sudden?**

What could also help is if someone could help me reproduce this OnDestory OnCreate behavior of the app. I don't know why android does this. Calling finish on the activity did not have the same result by the way.

If you need more info, please ask.